# activity forcestop when run in virtual device

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

help me
whats wrong in this code
i know that problem is in on create methods
when set on click listener for Commit button
when i want run the app in virtual device i get force stop
how can i fix that

```
public class Addmoney extends AppCompatActivity {
AutoCompleteTextView textv;
Context context = this;
private boolean cansend;
private RadioButton radioCreditor;
private RadioButton radioDebtor;
private Button Commit;
private int as = 0;//1=creditor;2=debtor

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    radioCreditor = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiocreditor);
    radioDebtor = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiocreditor);
    Commit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCommit);




    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addmoney);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btcheckid);
    textv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textuser);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Editable str = textv.getText();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showprogresscheckid(true);
            checkID check = new checkID(str.toString(), context);
            check.execute();
        }
    });
    Commit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Editable str = textv.getText();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkID check = new checkID(str.toString(), context);
            check.execute();
        }
    });
}

void showprogresscheckid(final boolean turn) {
    ProgressBar pr = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarcheckid);
    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btcheckid);
    bt.setVisibility(turn ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    pr.setVisibility(turn ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    return;
}

class checkID extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    String user;
    String mLink = "http://test.kholaseketab.ir/checkid.php";
    Context contex;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        if (integer == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (integer == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "not", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "e4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        showprogresscheckid(false);
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
    }

    public checkID(String User, Context cnt) {
        super();
        contex = cnt;
        user = User;

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF8");
            URL mylink = new URL(mLink);
            URLConnection connect = mylink.openConnection();

            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String res = reader.readLine();
            if (res.trim().equals("ok")) {

                return 1;

            } else if (res.trim().equals("not")) {

                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }


}
}
```

and my layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"


android:background="@mipmap/light"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="right">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="check user"
            android:id="@+id/btcheckid"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" />

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressBarcheckid"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textuser"
            android:text="mohsen"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Az Creditor"
            android:id="@+id/radiocreditor"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:keepScreenOn="false"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Az Debtor"
            android:id="@+id/radiodebtor"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Cost :"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|left"
        android:enabled="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Details :"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Commit"
    android:id="@+id/btnCommit"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Logcat:

```
 02-03 18:06:41.163 10733-10733/com.example.mohsen158.test1 E/GMPM:      
    GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
02-03 18:06:41.167 10733-10733/com.example.mohsen158.test1 E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
02-03 18:06:41.187 10733-10747/com.example.mohsen158.test1 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
02-03 18:06:41.563 10733-10733/com.example.mohsen158.test1 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-03 18:06:41.563 10733-10733/com.example.mohsen158.test1 E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
02-03 18:06:41.567 10733-10733/com.example.mohsen158.test1 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-03 18:06:41.567 10733-10733/com.example.mohsen158.test1 E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
02-03 18:06:44.223 10733-10733/com.example.mohsen158.test1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.mohsen158.test1, PID: 10733
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mohsen158.test1/com.example.mohsen158.test1.Addmoney}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                 at com.example.mohsen158.test1.Addmoney.onCreate(Addmoney.java:62)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your AndroidMainifest. have you using any Goolge API?

Comment: missing resuorce "R.string.google_app_id " in string.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This two lines should be at top of onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method because without inflating xml you are going for finding radio buttons it's wrong step so move as starting line in onCreate()

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_addmoney);
```

Answer (score 0):

put these code after `setContentView()`

```
radioCreditor = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiocreditor);
radioDebtor = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiocreditor);
Commit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCommit);
```

before setting view of your activity, you cannot use `findViewById`, it will not find any view/controller.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `setContentView.`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_XML);
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Following 3 lines move

```
 radioCreditor = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiocreditor);
    radioDebtor = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiocreditor);
    Commit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCommit);
```

after

```
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_addmoney);
```